# Amazon Linux AMI: Can't find PHP-FPM www.conf file for PHP 5.5.7 with Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, php

When using Nginx with PHP 5.3.3 and PHP-FPM, the www.conf was located at

```
/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

but now that I have installed PHP 5.5.7, can't find this file anymore. I have to change the settings for

```
listing.onwer
listing.group
user
group
```

do I have to manually create this file? Or does it read from somewhere else? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay found it, it was a different name located at

```
/etc/php-fpm-5.5.conf
```